# How to unlock transform on bone - to move it, not just rotate?

Tags: blender, rigging, bones

I was trying to create IK constraint following a Nathan Vegdahl tutorial, and everything was nice and shiny, until I tried to actually move a bone. It's not moving, only rotating. I see that transform lock panel on location is grey and completely locked, and I have no idea what's wrong.

[image: Screenshot of bone and inspector panels]

Comment: Did you know we have a dedicated [Blender StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)? While questions asking about how to use Blender to implement game assets & features are not off-topic here, you might find there's a higher density of users able to answer your questions about Blender specifics on the tool-specific SE. Please note that cross-posting is discouraged here, so if you decide to post this question on the Blender SE, please delete the copy here, so we don't split the answers between two different sites.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is normal behaviour. A bone is [defined by two points](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/rigging/armatures/bones/structure.html), the head and tail (also called root and tip).

When a bone is connected to its parent bone, in pose mode you are unable to move the head, you can only rotate the bone so that its tail is in a different location.

To move the head of the bone you need to rotate its parent bone so that the connecting point is in a different location.

Blender provides user feedback by fading out the location of the bone when you can't directly edit that property using the current selection.